# Error: Target of assignment expands to non-language object, when using eval(parse())

Tags: r, parsing, eval

**Example Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(15706, 15707, 15708, 15709, 
15712, 15713, 15714, 15715, 15716, 15719), class = "Date"), MidPrs_JPY = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 0.00102, 0.00102, 0.00102, 0.00102, 0.00102, 0.00102, 
NA), BID_EUR = c(NA, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 
2e-04, 2e-04, 2e-04), ASK_EUR = c(NA, -2e-04, -3e-04, -7e-04, 
-3e-04, -4e-04, -4e-04, -7e-04, -5e-04, -5e-04), BID_GBP = c(NA, 
0.0048, 0.0048, 0.0048, 0.0048, 0.0048, 0.0048, 0.0048, 0.0048, 
0.0048), ASK_GBP = c(NA, 0.0042, 0.0042, 0.0042, 0.0042, 0.0042, 
0.0042, 0.0042, 0.0042, 0.0042), BID_USD = c(0.0034, 0.0034, 
0.0034, 0.0034, 0.0034, 0.0034, 0.0034, 0.0034, 0.0034, 0.0034
), ASK_USD = c(0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 
0.003, 0.003, 0.003)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

namesV <- c("EUR", "GBP", "USD")
```

**Question**

When playing around with `eval(parse(...))` while writing a loop I noticed that one is not able to assign to a statement resulting from `eval(parse(...))`. This does not make sense to me since one can call a column by using this method but apparently can not assign new values.

What I mean by not being able to assign but call:

```
eval(parse(text = paste0("RepoCal$BID_", namesV[1])))
```

Allows me to call the column, however:

```
eval(parse(text = paste0("Repomid$MidPrs_", namesV[1]))) <- eval(parse(text = paste0("Repomid$MidPrs_", namesV[2])))
```

results in the Error:

> target of assignment expands to non-language object

I am grateful for any tips that would help me to understand the underlying problem or even solve it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is obscure but what this essentially tells us is that you can’t perform assignments to arbitrary expressions. `eval(parse(…))` isn’t a *name*, you can’t assign to it.<sup>1</sup>

The fundamental problem you want to solve doesn’t require any of that, luckily (because otherwise you’d be in a right pickle). Instead, you need to perform `[[` subsetting rather than `$` subsetting:

```
Repomid[[paste0('MidPrs_', namesV[1L])]] <- Repomid[[paste0('MidPrs_', namesV[2L])]]
```

Simply put, the syntactic form `foo[['bar']]` is (more or less) equivalent to `foo$bar`, where `bar` is a quoted string in the first expression, but an unquoted name in the second one.

---

<sup>1</sup> It’s (quite a lot) more complicated than that, because you *can* assign to expressions in R which aren’t pure names. But ultimately they all need to resolve to a name somehow. The above doesn’t. But even if it did it probably wouldn’t work as you’d expect because you’re attempting to assign to the *result* of that `eval` call. And the result of that `eval` call is a *value*, not a *name*. R fundamentally doesn’t allow assigning to values.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, but with a slightly different scope. However, I think it's close enough to not warrant a second question. I want to assign a value to a specific index in a column of tibble. I tried several things already and haven't found anything on here. I would like to do something like: `data=tibble(row=c(1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3), col=c(1,2,3, 1,2,3, 1,2,3), x=c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3))
eval(parse(text="data"))$row[n]=2` I want to loop over several similar dataframes and n. If anybody has an idea, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: @Lotte For all these questions, the answer is: have your data.frames *inside a (named) list* instead of as separate variables. There’s *never* a reason to have them as variables — literally everything gets easier by having them in a list. Once you have that, you can write `mylist$data$row[n] = 2`, or `mylist[[name]]$row = 2`, where `name = "data"`.